# How to reshape numpy array to ise KNN classifier?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, knn, numpy-ndarray

I have .npy files which contain 3 dim arrays. 
After applying reshape to arrays, it still doesnt work. Here is the code.

```
ta = np.load('class_a.npy', mmap_mode='r')
tb = np.load('class_b.npy', mmap_mode='r')
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
ta.reshape(-1)
tb.reshape(-1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ta, tb, test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is the error that I get

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try assigning them back: `ta = ta.reshape(-1)` and so on. Or put them directly into `train_test_split(ta.reshape(-1), ...)`

Comment: Well I found my mistake! I simply didn't pass correct value to classifier!